# Permission for anonymous user

Tags: 8, users

I got custom registration form under `/user/register` URL but anonymous user gets `denied access` what type of permissions should I set.
 
I tried:

```
 requirements:
   _permission: 'access content'
```

and

```
requirements:
   _permission: 'none'
```

or I deleted it completly but it didn't help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

'access content' should be good in general, check it under "people/permissions" to seem if also anonymous users have right to "access content". 
You can also declare:

```
_access: 'TRUE'
```

In this case you don't need the permission part, this one should definitely work!

Comment: It is working. I accidentialy might have turn off access content for anonymous users. Thanks for feedback.

Comment: It should be 'TRUE' as string

Comment: True: even tho without string it's also working, string shall be used in all cases.

Answer (score 3):

The above answer did not work until I added the quote marks around TRUE. See the following YAML example placed in my_module.routing.yml

```
my.module:
    path: '/my-module'
    defaults:
      _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\MyModuleController::connection'
    requirements:
      _access: 'TRUE'
```

Answer (score 1):

The most correct way is use the _persmission as following:

```
custom_module.add:
  path: '/tools/add'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Add new tools'
    _controller: '\Drupal\custom_module\Controller\ToolsInputPage::render'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this.

```
  requirements:
    _role: 'authenticated'
```

or use the User service.

```
  requirements:
    _user_is_logged_in: 'TRUE'
```